# Momentum as Generator of Translations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, commutator

I understand from some studies in mathematics, that the generator of translations is given by the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$.

Similarly, I know from quantum mechanics that the momentum operator is $-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}$.

Therefore, we can see that the momentum operator is the generator of translations, multiplied by $-i\hbar$.

I however, am interested in whether an argument can be made along the lines of *"since $\frac{d}{dx}$ is the generator of translations, then the momentum operator must be proportional to $\frac{d}{dx}$".*  If you could outline such an argument, I believe this will help me understand the physical connection between the generator of translations and the momentum operator in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Well, if you think about it, Taylor expansion about $p_{0}$ is really $\left.\exp(i\Delta p\partial_{x})f(p)\right|_{p=p_{0}}=f(p_{0}+\Delta p)$ for some constant $\Delta p$, with $\hbar=1$. That's the general idea here

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the position representation, the matrix elements (wavefunction) of a momentum eigenstate are $$\langle x | p\rangle = \psi_p(x) = e^{ipx}$$  The wavefunction shifted by a constant finite translation $a$ is $$\psi(x+a)$$  Now the momentum operator is the thing which, acting on the momentum eigenstates, returns the value of the momentum in these states, this is clearly $-i\frac{d}{dx}$.

For our momentum eigenstate, if I spatially shift it by an infinitesimal amount $\epsilon$, it becomes $$\psi(x+\epsilon) = e^{ip(x+\epsilon)} = e^{ip\epsilon}e^{ipx} = (1+i\epsilon p + ...)e^{ipx}$$ i.e. the shift modifies it by an expansion in its momentum value. But if I Taylor expand $\psi(x+\epsilon)$, I get $$\psi(x+\epsilon)= \psi(x)+\epsilon \frac{d}{dx} \psi(x)+... = \psi(x)+i\epsilon(-i\frac{d}{dx})\psi(x)+... $$  So this is consistent since the infinitesimal spatial shift operator $-i\frac{d}{dx}$ is precisely the operator which is pulling out the momentum eigenvalue.

Comment: Though the above is a simplified version. This wiki has some good foundations to the above. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_operator_(quantum_mechanics)#Momentum_as_generator_of_translations

Comment: This answer shows that the assumption $\langle x \vert p \rangle = e^{ixp}$ is equivalent to the statement that $p$ is the generator of translation.  (You can start from either one and derive the other one.)  But when I read the question, it seems to me like the OP is asking for something much more fundamental than that.

Comment: An explanation using Lie groups would be neat.