# Black Body Radiation similarity to Hawking Radiation

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, astrophysics, thermal-radiation, hawking-radiation

Do black body radiation of a 40-Earth mass osmium planet with radius of Earth which was just formed and has a temperature of 10000 degrees Celcius emit photons not just near it but even at infinity kind of like a black hole does? The only difference is that Hawking Radiation increases but the osmium planet Radiation will decrease unless there is another energy source from the core. So in theory it is possible to send information faster than light by just heating up the planet and then telling somebody 1 light year away to detect radiation particles because some of them can spawn many osmium planet radii away and then information can be sent faster than light through this process. Assume that the object is not surrounded by any matter and is in intergalactic space and atleast 10000 light years from any other object.

The reason is because in Hawking Radiation photons don't necessarily have to spawn in 4-5 event horizon radii, and can spawn in millions of radii away so there should be an analog for non-black hole objects that radiate as well right?

Comment: Why do you think there is anything special about *osmium*?

Comment: *information can be sent faster than light through this process* No. When you reach that conclusion, it means that you’ve reasoned incorrectly. This is non-mainstream physics, and a personal theory, and both are off-topic here.

Comment: You may find this study interesting: https://bigthink.com/starts-with-a-bang/hawking-radiation-black-holes/ - It claims the horizon is not needed, compares the Hawking radiation to the Schwinger effect in electromagnetism, and explains that most radiation is created at 25% above the Schwarzschild radius. The latter is because the radiation is proportional to the tidal forces that fall as the third power of the radius, but the time dilation that affects the energy depends on the distance to the horizon. Combining both formulas explains the result.

Comment: Both gravitational and electromagnetic interactions are instantaneous, but this does not mean that gravity or electromagnetism propagates faster than light and does not allow the superluminal transfer of information. For example, the Earth is pulled by the Sun toward the actual position of the Sun in the sky 4 Sun’s diameters ahead of where we see the Sun with the 8-minute delay for the speed of light: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/364427 - https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9909087 - https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/492870

Comment: I know that the fundamental forces don't violate the speed of light rule but what about quantum tunneling? What if a photon tunnels from a flashlight to a spot one light year away and then there happens to be a detector one light year away?Wouldn't there be a measurement which can be stored until the person reaches the measurement device?

Comment: @MiltonTheMeme Quantum tunneling is equivalent to passing through a wall, but without exceeding the speed of light.

Answer (score 2):

No, the hot osmium planet generates blackbody photons by vibrations among the electrons near the surface, not in the nonlocal way Hawking radiation is emitted due to event horizons.

Both hot planets and black holes have blackbody spectra (give or take a few details of emissivity and greybody factors) because they represent the maximum entropy state of a photon gas (in the hole case, also a gas of other particles - there are corrections for higher temperatures). But the mechanisms of generating them are very different.

And no, you don't get superluminal signalling this way.

Comment: Aren't electrons moving around causing a quantum field disturbance, and so isn't there a non zero probability of a photon spawning further away instead of close to the electron or does the photon always spawn somewhere?

Comment: @MiltonTheMeme You’ve heard “non-local” more than once already, but in a misleading way. In relation to the event horizon, “non-local” does not mean far away. The position of the Schwarzschild-like horizon in space is given by its radius and therefore is local. So we know exactly where it is, but we also know that it does not form until some (infinitely) **distant** (“non-local”) moment of the cosmological time. So it is non-local in time, not in space.