# Is it possible to distinguish the intensity and the frequency of the graviton?

Tags: particle-physics, gravity, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves

The wave equation of the graviton was assumed to be similar to that of the EM waves, which a "frequency" parameter could be identified by comparison. However, in EM, there was intensity as well. (And it was one of the seven fundamental unites in the previous ISU.)

Unlike the EM, people usually mentioned the phenomenon of the gravity in the terms of of how "strong" the acceleration, or "high" the curvature. But the intensity and the frequency of the graviton was rarely discussed together. For example, what if the different "frequency" of graviton "diffract" at different angle? What if the "receptor" of the graviton "truncate" at a certain intensity?

Is it possible to distinguish the intensity and the frequency of the graviton?

*Cautious(Related Post): [Is the graviton hypothetical?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119254/is-the-graviton-hypothetical)

Comment: If you have the answers for photons, you have them, ipso facto, for gravitons, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can understand classical gravitational waves as small perturbations moving in a background spacetime. In this picture, a gravitational wave is very similar to an electromagnetic wave. A general configuration of gravitational waves is a superposition of plane waves with different frequencies, wave vectors, and amplitudes. The frequency and amplitude of a gravitational wave can be measured by its effect on freely falling test masses, such as the mirrors in an interferometer like LIGO or Virgo.

A graviton is a quantized fluctuation in the gravitational field, much like a photon is a quantized fluctuation in the electromagnetic field. Again, we can understand many of the properties of gravitons by direct analogy to photons. A graviton (like a photon) has a frequency $f$, but not an amplitude per se. A graviton carries energy, which is related to its frequency by $E=hf$, where $h$ is Planck's constant.

As @annav points out in the comments, one has to be a little careful with interpreting the frequency of a photon, since a photon is not a classical wave. Ultimately, this is related to the wave-particle duality. In some circumstances, a photon behaves like a wave, and in others, like a particle. In circumstances where we can treat a photon as a wave, then it has a frequency $f$. You can also understand the frequency of a photon by building a coherent state of many photons with the same frequency and a coherent phase; then you will build up a classical electromagnetic wave that has that same frequency in the ordinary, classical sense.

While the formalism of quantum field theory is clear about what properties a graviton should have (at least at sufficiently low energies), one difference between gravitons and photons is that gravitons have not been detected and there is very little chance we will see one detected in our lifetimes; in fact it is [debatable whether a single graviton is detectable even in principle.](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0217751X1330041X)

Comment: "A graviton (like a photon) has a frequency f," This is misleading. A frequency is **related** to the photon and the graviton, but what identifies them is just energy hf , momentum, mass zero and spin . The frequency is the one seen in the wave that is built up by a multitude of gravitons(photons). this simple double slit single photon experiment makes this clear https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/

Comment: @annav I see what you are getting at, but I'm not sure I agree. Theoretically, a photon (or a graviton) is a fundamental excitation in a given mode of the electromagnetic (or gravitational) field, and that mode has a frequency. In any case, I think phrases like "a photon with frequency $f$" or "a photon's frequency is $f$" or "a photon has frequency $f$" are standard.

Comment: The reason I commented it is *because* it is standard and not confusing for the cognoscenti, but it is a misleading statement leading to questions as above, because the word "frequency" implies variation in space time , or some coordinates, which is not true for the standard model the question is about. photons are defined in the standard model table with fixed mass zero.

Comment: @annav I think I really disagree with the science behind what you are saying. A photon, like any quantum particle, exhibits wave-particle duality, and so has wavelike characteristics (such as a frequency) in some situations, and particlelike characteristics (such as a position) in others. The example you pointed to of the double slit experiment doesn't prove that a single photon does not have a frequency; it shows that if you measure the position of a single photon, you always locate the photon in one location. Additionally, we can't use a coherent state to define the frequency of a fermion...

Comment: ...even though $E=hf$ is just as valid for fermions as it is for bosons. In fact it could be somewhat misleading to say that we can only see the effects of the frequency of a photon by building a classical wave out of many photons, since that could be taken to mean that the frequency of an electron is somehow less real. I do appreciate that these points are difficult for beginners, and I'll add a note to the answer, but I don't think we should avoid saying the photon has a frequency.

Comment: Your edit is fair enough on the subject, although not in my point of view, one of an experimental physicist, which considers the mathematics as just model descriptors, not physical reality.

Comment: @annav Respectfully, I don't think this is an issue of theory vs experiment, even though I admit my bent is more theoretical. How can you explain [atom interferometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_interferometer), even with [fermionic atoms](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0402328), if you say that individual atoms do not have a frequency?

Comment: lets not argue on different povs, I explain  it with the same quantum mechanical model  that explains the single electron double slit, atoms instead of electrons . All matter has a final wavefunction  giving probabilities of interaction, the wave in the probability.

Comment: p.s. this answer of mine here explains what I mean extensively. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/360902/terminology-confusion-particle/360949#360949

Comment: @annav Fair enough, no need to argue :) Not that we are very likely to meet in person, but in a hypothetical universe where we did, I would love to talk about this over coffee. I can't say that I agree with your point of view (although I am sure that feeling is mutual!), and I definitely do not consider myself a platonist (I wouldn't say quantum fields are *real*, just the best theoretical description we have of many phenomena as of today), but I do find this approach (which we might call "shut up and detect" instead of "shut up and calculate") very interesting.