# Can all types of particle be created in quantum fluctuation?

Tags: vacuum, fermions, virtual-particles, bosons

In quantum / vacuum fluctuation, a pair of virtual particles is formed. But can all different types of particles be created, both virtual fermions and virtual bosons? For example electrons, quarks, photons, W boson...?

Comment: Define "quantum fluctuation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual particles don't exist. They are a computational device used in calculating interactions between quantum fields. For more on this see [What actually are virtual particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286721/what-actually-are-virtual-particles) and [Do virtual particles actually physically exist?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185110/do-virtual-particles-actually-physically-exist)

Furthermore vacuum fluctuation also don't exist, or at least not in the sense of pairs of (non-existant) virtual particles appearing and disappearing. For more on this see [Are vacuum fluctuations really happening all the time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146003/are-vacuum-fluctuations-really-happening-all-the-time)

However, we do perform calculations that involve virtual particles when calculating the properties of a field theory vacuum, and your question is reasonably interpreted as asking if we need to consider all possible types of particles when calculating the vacuum properties. And the answer is that yes we do need to consider all possible particles, that is calculating the properties of the Standard Model vacuum requires consideration of all the particles in the Standard Model.