# Relation between energy-time uncertainty principle and virtual particles

Tags: particle-physics, energy-conservation, time, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, virtual-particles

The energy-time uncertainty principle, given by, $$\Delta E\Delta t\geq\frac{\hbar}{2},$$

can be used to explain the existence of virtual particles which violate the law of conservation of energy. That is, the smaller the uncertainty in time, $\Delta t$, the greater $\Delta E$ that is needed to ensure that this relation holds. My question however is this: What is stopping both the uncertainty in time and the uncertainty in energy being large simultaneously?

From what I can tell, a simultaneously large $\Delta t$ and $\Delta E$ would not violate this relation, so why do virtual particles have such short lifetimes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Energy conservation of Virtual Particles - Quantum Fluctuation?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143038/). See also [Virtual particles with almost infinite energy?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304192), [Virtual Photon in Electron Scattering Feynman diagram](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/294177)

Comment: The uncertainty in time does not work as you think it does, and cannot be used to show what you say, cf. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53802/50583