# Why internal lines in a Feynamann diagram represent virtual particles

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

I am trying to understand the argument for why internal lines in a Feynman diagram are virtual particles that do not obey the energy-momentum relation.

For the specific case of the following Feynman diagram, I was given the argument that the energy and momentum of the photon are over-constrained, hence the photon violates one constraint ie. the energy-momentum relation.

[image: Electron Scattering Feynman diagram]

However I fail to see why this is the case. This is my understanding: $E_1$, $E_2$, $p_1$, and $p_2$ are known as they are experimental parameters, so this leaves 6 unknowns (energy and momentum of the final states and of the photon). If I assume all of them follow the energy-momentum relation then this is reduced to 3 unknowns. Energy is conserved in each vertex which gives the relation between the remaining unknowns leaving 1 degree of freedom.

Is there any constraint I am missing? The only other reason I can think of is that the energies of the two final electrons are experimentally found not to depend on each other, meaning that this requires 2 degrees of freedom instead of one. Is this maybe the case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What actually are virtual particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286721/what-actually-are-virtual-particles)

Answer (score 2):

Energy and momentum are conserved on internal lines, which means that the mass shell condition cannot hold (as you can establish with a simple calculation).
$$ m^2\ne p^2 = E^2 - \mathbf p^2$$
 The question of whether internal lines represent "virtual" particles is primarily philosophical. Feynman for one regarded them as real particles which are not directly observed.

Comment: Maybe you mean are *not* conserved ? Else, your answer is impossible ot understand.