# Significance of Irreducible Representations

Tags: group-theory, group-representations

I am reading texts on QFT and they place a lot of emphasis on finding irreducible representations of the Lorentz/Poincare Group. I also recall some level of discussion from non-relativistic quantum mechanics, and I've also read up a bit on them in texts on representation theory. I am wondering however why they are particularly significant to physicists. If anyone could clarify this for me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the question about the theory of representation, or about the *irreducible* representation of group theory ?

Comment: An irreducible representation indicates that the quantum system is elementary; please see the following question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73593/why-do-we-say-that-irreducible-representation-of-poincare-group-represents-the-o