# Particle definition

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, particle-physics, group-representations, poincare-symmetry

I came across this statement in the book "Quantum Field theory and the Standard Model".

> "A particle can be defined as a set of states that mix only among themselves under Poincare transformations."

What does this statement mean?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21801/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73593/2451 ,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/224812/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277986/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we say that irreducible representation of Poincare group represents the one-particle state?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73593/)

Comment: Also a **set** of particles satisfies the suggested "definition". A crucial ingredient is missed: from a given state one can reconstruct all states using the action of Poincare' group. In other words the representation is irreducible.