Regarding physical phenomena related to operators of the form $\exp(x\partial_x)$
I am studying exponential operators, for example, of the form $\exp(x \partial_x)$. Do these operators appear or model any physical phenomena? or are they just abstract entities?

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240674/2451 and links therein.
